# How to overlay images using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to click on an image and see the enlarged version. How can I accomplish this using bootstrap?

I tried

```
<a className ="thumbnail" href="IMAGE_URL">
    <img className ="img-responsive" src ="IMG_TUMB_NAIL_URL" />
</a>
```

but that does not work.

Comment: Did you try applying the class on the img element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lightbox plugin :

http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/